# Integrate Redash metadata with Snowflake

Tags: metadata, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, access-control, redash

I have integrated Redash with Snowflake as one of the data sources.

We get value of parameters such as `query_id`, `query` and `user_name` in Redash metadata table `events` which gives us all the metadata related to queries executed on Redash historically.

Snowflake also stores the queries meta data in a table called `QUERY_HISTORY` which has information related to queries executed on snowflake historically. It has `user_name` and `role_name` fields but both of them store the name of Redash user which is associated with snowflake.

The information about which logged in user executed the query is missing. Also, there is no way (maybe some common identifier - query id) in any of the metadata information to map the queries in Redash meta data with the queries executed on snowflake.

Let me know if I am missing something or if there's some way we could achieve the same.

**Redash version: 7.0.0**

Comment: Not sure I understand.  You say the user_name is shown in Snowflake's account_usage.query_history view.  This should be the user who is logged in running the queries, correct?

Comment: It should be ideally. But in Redash there's this concept of user groups. All users in a group get the same access permissions. So all logged in users are mapped to a group which has a common connection with snowflake. So one snowflake user is mapped to one Redash group, but each Redash group can be mapped to n number of users.